# Numpy dot product and manual calculation gives incorrect result

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to multiply 2 matrices

```
a = [[0.8730616+0j, 0.8133501+0.3224322j], [0.8133501-0.3224322j, 0.87694746+0j]]
g = [[0.70813084+0j, 0.6563272+0.26035604j],[-0.6563272+0.26035604j, 0.70813084+0j]]

a_temp1 = np.dot(a, g)
```

And calculating values manually

```
a_temp2 = np.zeros((2, 2))
a_temp2[0,0] = a[0,0]*g[0,0] + a[0,1]*g[1,0]
a_temp2[0,1] = a[0,0]*g[0,1] + a[0,1]*g[1,1]
a_temp2[1,0] = a[1,0]*g[0,0] + a[1,1]*g[1,0]
a_temp2[1,1] = a[1,0]*g[0,1] + a[1,1]*g[1,1]
```

If I find the difference between a_temp1 and a_temp2, the difference is non-zero

```
a_temp1[0,0] = 0.0004709065+0.00013959408j
a_temp2[0,0] = 0.0004708767+0.00013959408j
```

Do you know why there is difference between both results?

Answer (score 0):

Your code did not work for me; I had to correct stuff:

```
import numpy as np
a = [[0.8730616+0j, 0.8133501+0.3224322j], [0.8133501-0.3224322j, 0.87694746+0j]]
g = [[0.70813084+0j, 0.6563272+0.26035604j],[-0.6563272+0.26035604j, 0.70813084+0j]]

a_temp1 = np.dot(a, g)

a_temp2 = np.zeros((2, 2), dtype=complex)

a_temp2[0,0] = a[0][0]*g[0][0] + a[0][1]*g[1][0]
a_temp2[0,1] = a[0][0]*g[0][1] + a[0][1]*g[1][1]
a_temp2[1,0] = a[1][0]*g[0][0] + a[1][1]*g[1][0]
a_temp2[1,1] = a[1][0]*g[0][1] + a[1][1]*g[1][1]

print(a_temp1[0,0]) # (0.0004708796665360956+0.0001395881537640122j)
print(a_temp2[0,0]) # (0.0004708796665361392+0.00013958815376402534j)

print(a_temp1[0,0] - a_temp2[0,0]) # (-4.3639137442541553e-17-1.3145951341386741e-17j)
print(np.finfo(complex).eps) # 2.220446049250313e-16
```

I'm not an expert on this, but the difference looks much more acceptable especially when compared to the machine epsilon.